# How to hidden footer component for home page?

Tags: angular, routes, components, show-hide

This is my `app.component.html` file:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

But what I want to do is I want to hide the footer component in `/home` route. How can I do that? (Please let me know if putting more code or information is needed?)

Answer (score 1):

You can know that you are in home component from the path:

```
In app.component.ts

page: string;

//See what is the current page from the path
this.page = this.route.parent.snapshot.url[0].path;

so in app.component.html

<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="page != 'home" ></app-footer>
```

So if you are in home component the footer component it is not rendered.